# Suitable error when limitting the number of args

Tags: python, error-handling

Which would be the suitable **base error** in Python for limiting the **number of args** passed in a function.

I'd like to limit it to 2 argument as follows:

```
def func(*args):

    if len(args) == 1:
        # Do one thing
        
    elif len(args) == 2:
        # Do another thing
    
    else:
        ## raise an error ##
```

Comment: Why not write two functions instead?

Comment: It would get out of the function logic

Comment: Then I think this SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/1964247/9479128 would probably answer your question, by subclassing TypeError

Comment: Oh great, @Nathan Furnal
Thanks for the info, althoug I wouldn't like to sublclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `TypeError` would be okay. This suggests the input is structurally incorrect.
[Doc here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError)

Answer (score 1):

You can raise an error with the `raise` keyword.

```py
else:
    raise TypeError
```

You can also specify custom information.

```py
    raise TypeError(f"func() takes exactly one argument ({len(args)} given)")
```

Comment: Thanks @sabz !
My doubt is what kind of error fits to this issue.
So, TypeError fits well then?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `TypeError`. This would suggest the input is structurally incorrect, i.e. too many arguments.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose a different solution which does not rely on error handling but on [multipledispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch). I do not recommend using this in production because it's not a base feature but I think it's interesting nonetheless. This does take care of the number of arguments problem though.

Here is an example where a function with the same name behaves differently based on arguments types as well as number of arguments. You'll need the [multipledispatch library](https://multiple-dispatch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch

@dispatch(int)
def func(x: int):
    return x**2

@dispatch(int, int)
def func(base: int, power: int):
    return base**power

@dispatch(int, str)
def func(base: int, power: str):
    return f"{base}^{power}"


func(3)
>>> 9

func(2, 3)
>>> 8

func(2, "3")
>>> '2^3'
```

Comment: Very interesting, thanks a lot!